# Degeneracy of relativistic hydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, atomic-physics

According to Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics, we can choose different parity for the wave functions of relativistic hydrogen atoms.

[image]

However, when calculating the state degeneracy, we don't consider this difference. Since two wave functions with different parity correspond to one same energy, this confuses me.

Comment: These statements apply to any dirac solution, not just to electrons in hydrogen.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question! Dirac's equation does not impact the parity of the wave function. However it states that electron and positron solutions have opposite parity. In principle one could therefore say that it has parity degenerate solutions. However it is believed that only particles exist of definite parity.